# How to set imageButton to top left corner of a subview (webview) in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, webview, android-relativelayout, android-imagebutton

I'm having trouble on setting the imageButton to top, left corner of my WebView, i have no idea on how to play with layouts (linear or relative), i tried lots of code blocks and none of them worked for me.

This is how i create my imageButton;

```
ImageButton mImageButton = new ImageButton(context);
        mImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.close_button);
        mImageButton.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(width, height));
        mImageButton.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        mImageButton.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
        mImageButton.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
```

and this is how i create and add my imagebutton to webview

```
        WebView mWebView = new WebView(context);
        mWebView.loadData(htmlContent, "text/html", "UTF-8");
        mWebView.addView(mImageButton);
```

[This is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cK7zQ.jpg)

any idea on how can i place it correctly without using xml, since i'm trying to do this for a jar file that will be distrbuted

Comment: Why don't you use layout files in xml ?

Comment: @sonic oh, i should have said that in the question, i'm creating a jar file that will be used for others, so that is not an option

Comment: according image u can use fream layout for this type view

Comment: @Naveen is right, you can use a Frame Layout and in that frame layout put the webview and the imageview

Comment: byt how @Harish as I wrote in the question "I have no idea on how to play with layouts"

Answer (score 0):

The below xml code will do it:

```
<RelativeLayout 
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    />
<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i can not use xml file for the explaing reason in the question

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put your views inside a `RelativeLayout`. So i assume you get a `RelativeLayout` object. The following code may work.
Create the layout :

```
RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(context)
```

Create the `WebView` and add it to the layout :

```
WebView mWebView = new WebView(context);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsWV = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(mRelativeLayout.getWidth(), mRelativeLayout.getHeight);
mParamsWM.addRule(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);//so the web view fill the layout
mWebView.setLayoutParams(mParamsWM);
mWebView.loadData(htmlContent, "text/html", "UTF-8");
mRelativeLayout.addView(mWebView);
```

Then for the button

```
ImageButton mImageButton = new ImageButton(context);
mImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.close_button);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsB = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
paramsB.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
paramsB.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
mImageButton.setLayoutParams(paramsB);
mImageButton.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
mImageButton.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
mRelativeLayout.addView(mImageButton);
mImageButton.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
```

Comment: well i dont have a relative layout object to use in this function (mRelativeLayout)

Comment: Then you should start by creating one of the size you want to use. This layout will allow you to place your view as you will.

Comment: can you help on creating the layout?

Comment: I edit my answer to add the creation of the layout. I also add this line `mParamsWM.addRule(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);` so the web view should fill the layout. I hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
frameLayout.setLayoutParams(
        new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

View mWebView = new View(this);
mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
mWebView.setLayoutParams(
        new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

ImageButton mImageButton = new ImageButton(this);
mImageButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.star_big_on);
mImageButton.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(200, 200));
mImageButton.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

frameLayout.addView(mWebView);
frameLayout.addView(mImageButton);

relativeLayout.addView(frameLayout);
```

relativeLayout variable in my example is container where you add all your elements. Additionally you should replace my View control with your WebView

Comment: can not resolve findViewById is the error i'm getting

Comment: @EvrenBaykan In this case i can't help you. You don't know basics of android. Sorry.